# Swift 3 - How to add navigation controllers buttons (as Back) after renewing - refresh and reload my viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to refresh my viewcontroller (reload it ) using `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController` as shown below in code, it works however when reloaded the novaigation controller is not there, I mean there a back button that can go to previous view controller it does not appear when I did that - any help

```
@IBAction func Save(_ sender: AnyObject) {
 UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UploadPhotoviewcontroller")
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

To deselect the picked image in elcimagepickercontroller use below code:

```
imagePicker.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Default back button, appearance and work in current navigationController navigation stack. If you  change rootViewController, this action will destroy you current navigation stack and all previous controllers. And you cant go back.

Change the rootViewController be bad practic. I think you have a problems with the architecture

Comment: I changed it to let UploadPhotoviewcontroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
                      "UploadPhotoviewcontroller") as! UploadPhotoviewcontroller
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(UploadPhotoviewcontroller, animated: true)       but the problem now it go back to main view then reload this one

Comment: For return to main controller in navigation stack you need use self.navigationController.popToRootViewController() in UploadPhotovie‌​wcontroller. What a you mean then say "need reload this one"?

Comment: yes this is happening - but it shows the previous view before loading UploadPhotovie‌​wcontroller which looks wrong

Comment: I can't understand, what a story you want create. Explain you navigation steps what a you want

Comment: I am using ELCimagePickercontroller to select multiple photos - once user select SAVE to save selected photo I want to reload the ELCimagePickercontroller so to do this I refreshed the Viewcontroller that runs it as I mentioned above. doing this made one problem either the "BACK" button disappear or dismissing the viewcontroller make it looks bad to user. I know it's confusing

Comment: what a reason for reload ELCimagePickercontroller. deselect the items?

Answer (score 0):

@jon when I try to comment it did not and I can not reply to your question as comment -  I do not know why

Exactly that is the reason

Comment: Then you no need reload controller. You need just deselected items. The ELCimagePickercontroller implement UITableView and you can use standard [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

Comment: @jon can not find any tableview member to the ELcimagepicker

Comment: ELCAlbumPickerController is UITableViewController - @interface ELCAlbumPickerController : UITableViewController <ELCAssetSelectionDelegate>

Comment: can you tell me how to use this class - I am sorry as I am new in swift